# API not working with nodejs https server

Tags: node.js, api, http, https

I am unable to hit API's i have created in nodejs https server while they are working fine in http server.

Here is the code how i have changed nodejs to https

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var app = express();
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('server.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('server.crt', 'utf8');

var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};

var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpsServer.listen(8000);
```

**EDIT**
But When i am hitting *curl -k -X GET [https://myurlandport/profile/id](https://myurlandport/profile/id_)* in terminal i am getting **proper response**

Comment: Whats the error message ?

Comment: No error.. it is not even hitting the server..